# What is the correct way to add relative path to URL in Java FX CSS File

Tags: css, url, javafx

I have a background image that I would like to use in my Java FX Application but I assume that I am unable to get the path (URL?) for the image right. I want to only use CSS files to do this and I prefer not to inline the code. I searched Google but everyone gives examples using just a single package structure. My directory structure looks like this:

```
 src/com/myapp/core        (com.myapp.core)
 src/com/myapp/view        (com.myapp.view)
 src/com/myapp/view/css    (com.myapp.view.css)
```

The file *DashBoard.fxml* is located in `com.myapp.view`
The css file *DashBoardStyle.css* is located in `com.myapp.view.css`
The image file *white-texture.jpg* is located in `com.myapp.view.css`

The code in the css file is:

```
.background {
-fx-background-image: url("src/com/myapp/view/css/white-texture.jpg");
-fx-background-repeat: repeat;
 }
```

The relevant code in the DashBoard.fxml file is

```
<stylesheets>
   <URL value="@css/DashBoardStyle.css" />
</stylesheets>
```

Comment: It isn't clear whether you have actually tried this or that you're only assuming. Please, test your own app package and then report the results. Include any error logs in your question.

Comment: I tested this, the background image does not show up on the application and when I add the CSS file in scene builder it says "The file white-texture.jpg does not exist" Since I got this message I assumed it's because I got the url formatting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

An image in the same directory as the css file doesn't need any relative path information.  So just use `-fx-background-image: url("white-texture.jpg");` .

If it's not in the same directory, then you have to add a relative path.  eg.  images/image.jpg if it's in a sub dir.  Or like ../images/image.jpg to go 'up' a directory then into the images dir.

Answer (score 0):

The relative path starts with both `System.getProperty("user.dir")` location and the location where your source (`*.java`) files are located.